# ElasticSearch multiple exact search on field returns no results

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I'm struggling with this, which I feel should work but maybe I'm doing something stupid.  This search:

```
{
   "query":
   {
     "bool":
     {
       "must":[
         {"match":{"Element.sourceSystem.name":"Source1 Source2"}}
       ]
  }
}
```

returns data for both Source1 and Source2.  Adding a terms search, as underneath, I would expect to return a subset of the first search with just the Source1s returned.  Nothing is returned, when run with the first query or on it's own.

```
{
  "query":
  {
    "bool":
    {
      "must":[
        {"match":{"Element.sourceSystem.name":"Source1 Source2"}},
        {"terms":{"Element.sourceSystem.name":["Source1"]}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I realise this is hard without seeing the documents, but suffice it to say that "Element.sourceSystem.name" exists and is available as the first search works fine - all input gratefully received.

Comment: Can you show response from elasticsearch for your first query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some things that are handled differently in `match` queries than in `terms` queries.

First of all, a detour to analyzers:

Assuming you are using the [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) of elasticsearch, which consists of a standard tokenizer and some token filters. The standard tokenizer will tokenize (split your text into terms) on spaces, punctuation marks and some other special characters. Details can be found in the Elasticsearch Documentation, so for now let's just say 'each word will be a term'.

The second, very important part of the analyzer is the lowercase filter. It will transform terms into lowercase. This means, later on, searching for `Source1` and `source1` should yield the same results.

So a short example:

> Input : "This is my input text in English." will be analyzed and end up with the following terms: "this", "is", "my", "input", "text", "in", "english".

All of this happens when you index a document into a `text` field for example. I assume the `Element.sourceSystem.name` is one of this type, since your normal match query seems to work.

Now, when you issue a match query with `"Source1 Source2"`, the analysis will also happen and transform it into tokens `source1` and `source2`. Internally it will then create 2 term queries in a boolean OR. So either `source1` or `source2` must match to be a result of your query.

> By the way, the match query supports a `minimum_should_match` property. You could specify, how many terms of your match query need to match.

Here's now the clue with the terms query. It does **not** analyze the text you provide. It's usually supposed to be used on fields of type `keyword`. Keyword fields are also not analyzed (for further information, please read the documentation of [mapping types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-types.html) - it is actually pretty important). So what does this mean?

- If I take my example from above, my index would contain `"this", "is", "my", "input", "text", "in", "english"`.
- A match query with `English` will match, because it will be analyzed to `english`
- A term/s query with `English` will never match, because there is no term `English` in my index. It is case sensitive.

I am very positive, if you would use `source1` in your terms query, it would match something. However, I highly doubt that your query is the way to go for your use case. Try using normal match queries when querying text fields and (in general - not always applicable) only use terms queries on keyword fields.

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed answer - solved it completely and also gave me a lot more information besides that will come in very useful and I'll be referring back to this (and the docs) a lot.