# ElasticSearch filtered query with operator AND and OR

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I'm intervening on an existing app which interacts with an elasticsearch sever and i'm seeing some weird responses, probably due to the fact that i'm new to elastic.

I have the indexed item below :

```
"_id": "59773d268770541557000012",
        "_score": 0.03282923,
        "_source": {
           "_id": "59773d268770541557000012",
           "active": null,
           "address": "dummy address",
           "center_ids": [],
           "consultation_site_ids": [],
           "coordinates": null,
           "created_at": "2017-07-25T14:44:22.270+02:00",
           "death_declaration_form_step_id": "56ddb086f0e0103b44000000",
           "end_of_pregnancy_form_step_id": "56c34e63f0e0105e65000000",
           "fax": "06.95.40.58.84",
           "form_step_ids": [
              "55361b215342491667030000",
              "5541f16252f131f6a125a375",
              "55361ba05342491667040000",
              "553610835342491667010000",
              "55361d225342491667050000",
              "5541f34a52f131f6a125a377"
           ],
           "hospital_id": "57c004905c5393772c002a62",
           "name": "test site d'encronologie",
           "phone": "06.95.40.58.84",
           "short_name": "test site d'encronologie d'endcronologie",
           "sites_union_ids": [],
           "state": "active",
           "updated_at": "2017-07-25T14:44:22.270+02:00",
           "url": "http://www.testurl.com",
           "user_ids": [],
           "warnings_threshold": null,
           "_type": "Site
```

AND I am querying the server with this query:

```
 "query":{  
  "filtered":{  
     "query":{  
        "bool":{  
           "should":[  
              {  
                 "multi_match":{  
                    "fields":[  
                       "name^5",
                       "name.edge^1",
                       "name.full^0.3"
                    ],
                    "query":"enc",
                    "type":"cross_fields"
                 }
              },
              {  
                 "match":{  
                    "name":{  
                       "query":"enc",
                       "type":"phrase_prefix",
                       "operator":"or"
                    }
                 }
              },
              {  
                 "match":{  
                    "name":{  
                       "query":"enc",
                       "type":"boolean",
                       "boost":5
                    }
                 }
              }
           ]
        }
     },
     "filter":{  
        "and":[  
           {  
              "term":{  
                 "hospital_id":"57c004905c5393772c002a62"
              }
           },
           {  
              "term":{  
                 "state":"active"
              }
           }
        ]
     }
  }
}}
```

**Which returns nothing (no hits)**

And the other hand, if I change the filter operator "AND" to "OR" I recieve my 1 hit.

I am talking about the "and" on the "filter" branch :

```
    "filter":{  
            "and":[
```

I realy don't understand how come OR works but not AND?

Then again when I change my query term from "enc" to "zzz_enc" in all the query{} of the first branch **WHILE keeping the "OR"** I have zero matches, even though the filter condition hospital_id and state are true on my item.

**Why does the filter operator behave like this ?**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which version of Elasticsearch are you using? Also, can you tell what the results would be, if you just execute the two filters as a single query each?

Comment: i'm using ES 1.7.6 (yes it's old, but it is in production :/)

If i execute the first without  i get my indexed item.

I haven't been able to execute only the second though.

Comment: What if you remove the queey and just keep the filter - does it still returns nothing?

Comment: Also try using 'match' query instead of 'term'  query inside the filter

Comment: `AND` and `OR` queries work as they suggest: all subqueries in `AND` have to match, whereas in `OR`, documents pass as soon as they fulfill one. Which in your case would mean that the document you are expecting does not match both term filters. If switching the `term` to a `match` query (as @TomerArazy suggest) works, it would point to the mapping configuration. And maybe pose the question if `term` is in fact the correct query to use?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. 

the app is using Elasticsearch-model for rails, so it's not easily customisable, not without careful impact managment, i'm trying to avoid that.


What bothers me is the fact that OR  does not pass when all the "term" are not true but the "filter" condtions are ? for me it should pass, unless if "filter" has a specific processing.

Comment: So, it seems like the cause of the problem is the fact that ES cannot match hospital_id with the one on the  search query "57c004905c5393772c002a62" even though it's the same.

I've conducted tests and I noticed that the attribute state is succesfully matched, but never the hospital_id.

I can't put my finger on why

Comment: Ok found it, I changed the mapping of this attribute to "not_analyzed" and it worked. thank you all !

Comment: Glad you were able to solve it. I know this is shameless self-promotion, but I made a post not long ago about analyzers & term vs match queries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45077406/elasticsearch-multiple-exact-search-on-field-returns-no-results/45103907#45103907 I don't know if this helps you to better understand how ES works, but in any case, I really really think that understanding these basics will help a great deal when working with ES (or any lucene based framework)

Comment: No shame in sharing knowledge :) 
I'll read it carefully on my lunch break today.
Thank you again for your assistance.