# Elasticsearch 'must' query with multiple criteria

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Trying to get python-elasticsearch or curl to return the appropriate results when using bool and must queries.

I know the document is in my query, I can find it with 'should'; however, I need both criteria to be satisfied so I try to do the same query with 'must'.  When I use 'must' the document in question is not returned.

**With Should**

```
$ curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/polarion/subtype1/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
   "query" : {
      "constant_score" : {
         "filter" : {
            "bool" : {
              "should" : [
                 { "term" : {"project" : "AMQ"}},  
                 { "term" : {"test-type" : "functional"}}]
           }
         }
      }
   }
}
'

"hits" : {
    "total" : 3,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "polarion",
        "_type" : "subtype1",
        "_id" : "AV3s-vbF8T4AI9Zj3GkM",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "project" : "AMQ",
          "query" : "test-metrics",
          "test-type" : "functional",
          "2017-08-16" : 1916
        }
      },
```

**With Must**

```
$ curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/polarion/subtype1/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
   "query" : {
      "constant_score" : {
         "filter" : {
            "bool" : {
              "must" : [
                 { "term" : {"project" : "AMQ"}},  
                 { "term" : {"test-type" : "functional"}}]
           }
         }
      }
   }
}
'


{   "took" : 0,   "timed_out" : false,   "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0   },   "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]   } }
```

Comment: pretty sure it is because the `project` field is analyzed (i.e. it has `text` type). You can either switch to using the `match` query instead, or stick with `term` but search for `amq` in lowercase instead of `AMQ`

Comment: Adding to Val's comment above, or you can change your mapping from text type to keyword type then it will match the terms as its exact value

Answer (score 0):

change

```
{"term": {"project": "AMQ"}}
```

to

```
{"term": {"project": "amq"}}
```

OR we can substitute term with match and use 'AMQ'.

```
{"match": {"project": "AMQ"}}
```

Comment: While this will solve this particular problem, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45077406/elasticsearch-multiple-exact-search-on-field-returns-no-results/45103907#45103907) might be an interesting read.